# convert json symbols to html

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a json file that contain texts, In this json there is also math symbol like sqrt.
Im using this json file in javaScript component that knows to convert this text to form.
example of line from the json file with math symbol.

```
"tex": "\\text{What is } \\sqrt{169} \\text{?}"
```

when I added a css style

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the div who holds that texts, all math symbol disappear.
without this style I have elements that outstanding from the parent div.

there is another way to define those symbols?
thanks

Comment: This sounds likely to be an issue with whatever javascript component you're using to transform these symbols into HTML entities; modifying an element's CSS shouldn't change its contents, and the string you've shown wouldn't normally be displayed as math symbols.  Can you please include enough code in the question to allow people to reproduce the issue? [mcve]

Comment: Looking from the downvotes on my deleted answer, people seem to disagree that HTML entities inside the text are a good solution to this. An explanation would be nice so I also learn something.

Comment: @Shilly your answer had barely anything to do with the question.  Presumably it's already being converted into HTML entities by the unnamed javascript component; the question was why adding `overflow:hidden` breaks that (which can't be answered without seeing the javascript.)